# Pass dynamic data from parent to child component in Angular 7

Tags: angular, input, angular7, ionic4, ngfor

I am having this code:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let product of products">
            <ion-label>
              {{ product }}
            </ion-label>
</ion-item>
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="states.Product">
      <product-details></product-details>
</ng-container>
```

I want to pass to the `product-details` child component the value of product from the *ngFor of the parent component. Should I use Input or service? please give example.

Comment: Use an Input for this. Services are more useful when you need to keep state over multiple components especially if they are not related to one another. This is a direct relationship and it makes sense to use an Input()

Comment: @Sam please give example with dynamic data as I wrote.

Comment: Here are some examples, https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding. This is a good read to get an understanding of how child / parent can talk to one another.

Comment: In your code, the product-details selector is outside the scope of *ngFor (it is closed with ion-item selector). Are you sure this is the intended behavior? If not please modify the code.

Comment: @MichaelD exactly. no, it is an intented behavior. That is why I posted here. With Input does not work. Is there any other way?

Comment: In this case how are you determining which product to pass to the `<product-details>` component? And how many of these child components do you want to create? Can you create a stackblitz, and explain your desired outcome.

Comment: @Sam the ion-label is clickable and I want to pass the value of product that was clicked. sorry for not posting the whole code but I cannot due to work restructions. I am creating one child component each time I click the ion-label.

Comment: If it's clickable, then send the 'product' variable to the event handler, then it can be used as a local variable. For eg., in the ion-label selector, do (mouseup)="mouseUp(product)"; then store it in a local variable that can be used in product-details selector. However, I do wonder if you're willing to filter the product inside ng-container, then this convolution can be bypassed by adopting one of the answers below.

Comment: @MichaelD u made my day. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, you want to access the variable 'product' outside the scope of `*ngFor`. I can't recommend this behavior but since you have an event-handler within the scope, one way to achieve it is to send the value in the event handler:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let product of products">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label (mouseup)="mouseUp(product)">
      {{ product }}
    </ion-label>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="states.Product">
      <product-details [productName]='product'></product-details>
    </ng-container>
  </ion-item>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `@Input` decorator for data passing from parent to child component. For dynamic binding, you can use attribute binding `[]` like below -

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let product of products">
   <ion-item>
       <ion-label>
          {{ product }}
       </ion-label>
      <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="states.Product">
          <product-details [productName]='product'></product-details>
      </ng-container>
   </ion-item>
</ng-container>

@Input('productName') productName: type
```

Also, keep in mind you can get the value passed in the `ngOnInit` life cycle hook, not in the constructor of the child component.

Refer to the working example below for your reference.

## <kbd>[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o56ktr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)</kbd>

Comment: it does not work because the product-details selector is outside the scope of *ngFor. That is the reason why I posted. Is there any other way? –

Comment: @KathrineHanson check my updated answer, also `product-details` is within the scope

Answer (score 1):

Your product details are not inside `*ngFor`, you can only pass `product` to `<product-details>` if it is inside the scope of it. I of course recommend using input here, because it helps keeping your `product-details` component independent and have a role of presentation only component. If you used a service, it would rely on the fact that the service has to get data from somewhere, which would make `product-details` too complex in this case.
Here is example:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let product of products">
  <ion-label>
    {{ product }}
  </ion-label>
  <div [ngSwitch]="state">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="states.Product">
      <product-details [product]="product"></product-details>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

And in your **product-details.component.ts**:

```
@Input() product: Product;
```

Comment: if you just copied it the way it is, probably it doesn't, because I don't know what your `ngSwitch` should operate with. Just delete `ngSwitch` and `*ngSwitchCase` and then try it.

Comment: No. The problem is that the product-details selector is outside the scope of *ngFor. That is the reason why I posted. Is there any other way?

Comment: but that's what I said that if you move your product-details selector inside your `*ngFor` then you will have product available there. Otherwise I don't understand your intension. What exactly are you trying to achieve?